Google Sheets formula to move and clean an array of data
I have data related to product code and item name with the following data example:



Product Code
Item Name




A001
-



Book



Fruit



-






A002
Pen



-



Cloth






A003
-



-



Pencil



I want to clean it up into expected output as follows:

For the output, I have tried with formula:
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({TRIM(Dummy!B2:B), TRIM(Dummy!C2:C)}), "SELECT * WHERE Col2 <> '-'")

but the product code with the same row as the item name “-” is also deleted, is there any other formula to show the product code?

To easily take a copy of your sample data & test formulas (instead of screenshots), the recommended method is to create a markdown table. Use this tool to create the markdown_format & add it to your question. Additionally you can also share a sample sheet showcasing your input with realistic-demo data & expected output(manually entered). You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker to ease the process of sharing


Here's one possible approach which you may adapt accordingly:
=reduce(tocol(,1),unique(tocol(B2:B,1)),lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(a,hstack(c,filter(C:C,scan(,B:B,lambda(f,q,if(q="",f,q)))=c,C:C<>"-",C:C<>"")),))))



What comment should I add to code-only answers?

Hi, thank you for your help! I want to ask further. If in column A there are additional product codes such as: 01; 01; 01, can the range that was originally only for B be added with the range from A to B?

Share a test sheet showcasing your input & ideal expected output

Here is the test sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c8dl4QOzF81pF-7xUkN94w5KyucYdWq8YbATCANuAS0/edit?usp=sharing

Updated the formula

Thank you very much!
